# Auto insert In-app Products on Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app

I have implemented In-App billing on my Android App. Now I want to auto insert In-App Products on Google Play store from my site. Is there any API/Any other way to do that?

Comment: If you have those in-app products in .csv file, then you can directly import that .csv file into in-app products in playstore

Comment: Actually, What i want is, if i update product on my site, i want it to be automatically added to google play in-App Products.

Comment: I don't know is it possible or not? but my opinion is we have to update in play store  manually otherwise it will not update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. There is Api avaialble from Google to auto insert In-App Products on Google Play store from my site.

[Api Link to auto insert product on google play from server](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/insert)

Comment: hello, I looked into api but I can not understand that how to use this.please explain this in detail.

Comment: Hi, I've used this API to insert products to Play Store successfully(its active and visible) BUT only the products that I add via this API doesn't load in the client app when I use the Google Play billing library. Do you happen to know why? Did you also face a similar issue?